# How to Assign variable?

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, stored-procedures

I don't know how to assign value return from stored procedure into web api? how to pass variables througn angulrjs

I called serivice

```
var promisePost = crudService.candidatePost(Candidates);
            promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                alert("Sucessfully Inserted")

            }, function (err) {
                alert("NOt Inserted")
           });
```

my app.js is

```
 MyApp.service('crudService', function ($http, RESOURCES) {
 this.candidatePost = function (Candidate) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: RESOURCES.baseUrl + "saveCandidate",
        data: Candidate
    });
    return request;
}
```

});
my controller is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/saveCandidate")]

    public HttpResponseMessage AddDetail(Candidate ct)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constant.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         int rowInserted = 0;

        try
        {

           cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Insert_tblCandidate", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ct.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ct.Gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dob", ct.Dob);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob", ct.Mob);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", ct.EntryDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", ct.Note);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emial", ct.Emial);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", ct.Address);
            rowInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception obj)
        {
            if (rowInserted != 1)
            {
                var message = obj.Message;// string.Format("Insertion Of Data is not Succefully Executed");
                HttpError err = new HttpError();
                 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, err);

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {

                con.Close();
            }
        }
        var alertmessage = string.Format("Insertion Of Data is  Succefully Executed");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, alertmessage);

    }
```

My stored Procedure is

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
        FROM   sysobjects 
        WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[sp_Insert_tblCandidate]') 
               and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1 )
BEGIN
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_tblCandidate]
END

GO
 Create procedure [dbo].[sp_Insert_tblCandidate]
  (@Name varchar(50) ,
  @Gender char(1),
  @dob varchar(25),
  @Mob varchar(15),
  @EntryDate varchar(50),
  @Note varchar(100),
  @Emial varchar(50),
  @Address varchar(50)
)As
Begin
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCandidate] VALUES (@Name,@Gender,@dob,@Mob,@EntryDate,@Note,@Emial,@Address);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as CandidateId;
end
GO
```

My stored procedure purpose is insert data & return last inserted id. In this table id set to auto increment.Anyone can help me?

Comment: Your question makes no sense - AngularJS is a client-side language, any talking to databases must be done via a Server-Side controller, such as ASP.NET or Grails etc

Comment: Then you need to do a few things - 1. Call ExecuteScalar so that you can get the ID. 2. Call the WebAPI controller from your angular controller

Comment: Added a generic question but you should provide the error you are getting and also explain a bit better what your code is trying to achieve like the rowInserted check inside the catch

Comment: i wish to get the candidateId from storeprocedure? above web API code return only successfulyy inserted or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the new Id so you shouldn't be using

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But something that can handle the return value. Try changing it to

```
 rowInserted = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also right now you are checking in the catch the rowInserted which doesn't makes much sense.

Comment: how to return id from storeprocedure

Comment: Your select should be returning it as a table with a CandidateId column. You can also just do: RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: how to assign returned CandidateId to a variable?

Comment: Edited answer to explain how to assign. You don't need to change your sproc to use RETURN as long as it only returns a row and a column that code should work.

Comment: sorry. my purpose is get last inserted id then i'm also require to another table this id . so how to assign? my question is updated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a result from `ExecuteNonQuery()` as it only returns the number of rows affected for the query you just executed.

Since you are returning the SCOPE_IDENTITY(), you can either use `ExecuteReader()` or `ExecuteScalar()`.

```
rowInserted = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

or

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        rowInserted = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
    }
}
```

But using `SqlDataReader` is kinda unnecessary in this scenario.

Plus, just an observation; be careful when choosing between `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, `@@IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT`.